# Update 20H2 - A.K.A. Version 2009

Tags: windows

I have to do a Re-installation of Windows 10 Pro because I face some errors the last days (nothing serious tho). But the only version you can Re-Install Windows is Version 2009 (20H2)...The thing is that, I read more and more articles about bugs for this Version. Is it ok to do it now, or it's safer to wait a little bit for fixes and then go for it?
Thank you.

Comment: I've been using 2009 for weeks and weeks with no problem.

Comment: Ohh ok thank you for the reply!

Comment: @Gus998 Have you tried a repair install? _(launch v2009's `setup.exe` while booted to Windows and select to keep all files and programs)_

Comment: I've tried it some time ago...So now I'm ready to Re-install Windows, to make sure that it'll stop some of these errors (at least for a long time, if not completely).